# Show that $n$ has $2^{\omega(n) - 1}$ coprime factor pairs

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am trying to show that $n$ has $2^{\omega(n) - 1}$ coprime factor pairs. I'm pretty sure this is true but I don't see how to prove it. There is no obvious way to use induction.

Here is an example:

$30$ has $3$ distinct prime factors: $2, 3, 5$ so $\omega(30) = 3$. My conjecture predicts that $30$ has $2^{3 - 1} = 2^2 = 4$ coprime factor pairs.

We find they are: $(1, 2\cdot3\cdot5) $, $(2, 3\cdot5)$, $(3, 2\cdot 5)$, and $(5, 2\cdot3)$.

Can anyone provide a hint at how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: given the factorization of $n$ into powers of distinct primes, you can actually write down all the coprime factor pairs explicitly (and then count them).

Comment: Write down the prime factorization.  For each prime, decide whether it goes in the left or the right.  Divide by $2$ to kill the symmetry.

Comment: @ClydeKertzer I think he means you trying to count in general case. Let's say $n=p_1p_2\ldots p_k$ and all $p_i$'s are distinct, how will you count the number of coprime factor in this situation? Note that like in your example, the product of two components in a pair is again $n$, so in fact you can just count the first component. How could you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n= p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$. Then $\omega(n)=k$. Then the number of coprime factor pair has form $(x,y)$ where
\begin{align} \begin{cases} x \cdot y = p_1p_2\ldots p_k\\ \gcd(x,y)=1 \end{cases} \end{align}
Then for each $x$, you can determine exactly one $y$ that satisfies the above relations. Note that to form $x$, you can just pick $m$ prime in the set $\left\lbrace p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\right\rbrace$ and let $x$ be their product. There are $ \binom{k}{m}$ ways to choose such $m$-tuples of prime. So there are in total $\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m}=2^k$ coprime factor pairs. But there is a catch, each pair is repeated: for example, choosing $m=0$ and $m=k$ yields the same pairs, so in fact you only have $2^{k-1}$ pairs.